# How to programatically send report to a specific printer in Microsoft Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a couple of reports which I need to print to one of four printers.  Up to now in our old Access 2002 database, we've been getting the printer object from Application.Printers and assigning it to the report's Printer property at runtime.

```
Dim strPrinter as String
strPrinter = "\\server1\HP 4250 - Sales"
Reports("rptMyReport").Printer = Application.Printers(strPrinter)
```

Doing things this way means that the printer must be installed on the local PC, but it should be possible to print Access reports to any printer regardless of whether or not a print queue is installed for the logged in user, as long as the "Specific printer" is defined for a report, right?

Is there a better way of achieving this in Access 2010?

Comment: You can not print on a printer that is not installed at the local computer. Neither in Access nor anywhere else.

Comment: Hi @PhilS.  If I add a connection to a shared printer to my PC, go into the report definition and set the report to print to that specific printer, save the report definition and delete the connection to the shared printer from my PC, I am still able to print the report to that printer.  Even after restarting Access, my report will still print to the specific printer regardless of whether or not the print queue exists on my PC.  Not sure how Access achieves this, but it does.

Comment: If you install a printer with driver et. al. and then just remove it in Explorer, this might actually work, as Windows leaves the driver and much of the printer's settings in place and just hides them from view. But I doubt that you can rely on this working in every case.